# How is the display order of search results determined?

Tags: compass, palantir-foundry

I use the search menu to find files and objects. (Click the black menu on the left side of the Foundry screen -> "Search...") I can get the search results when I enter a query, but how is this order determined?

It takes time to discover what I'm looking for because irrelevant items are often displayed at the top. Even if I use the filter to specify the file type, it's difficult to find the desired one if there are many results.

I think it would be better if the user could explicitly specify the sort order.

Comment: We are aware that the search result scoring can be improved, and we’re actively working on it, but can’t give you an ETA for whenever the improvement will be released. This is nothing you can configure on your end at the moment.